# setHeadingAttributes to redefine a heading style in Documents w/ GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am hoping to re-define the heading styles for a document.   My understanding is that getHeadingAttributes and setHeadingAttributes would let me do this

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setheadingattributesparagraphheading-attributes

This is how I'm going about testing this --

```
function main() { 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();    

  styledef=body.getHeadingAttributes(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1); 

  Logger.log("Before: \n" + JSON.stringify(styledef) ); 

  styledef[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
  styledef[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#ffff00';

  body.setHeadingAttributes(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1, styledef);

  styledef=body.getHeadingAttributes(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

  Logger.log("After: \n" + JSON.stringify(styledef)); 

}
```

This Body has its headings attributes modified, as revealed by the Logger output:

```
    [17-10-04 09:20:53:379 MDT] Before: 
    {"FONT_SIZE":18,"ITALIC":false,"HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT":{},"INDENT_END":0,"INDENT_START":0,"LINE_SPACING":1,"UNDERLINE":false,"BACKGROUND_COLOR":null,"INDENT_FIRST_LINE":0,"SPACING_BEFORE":12,"SPACING_AFTER":0,"STRIKETHROUGH":false,"FOREGROUND_COLOR":"#000000","BOLD":true,"FONT_FAMILY":"Arial","VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT":{}}

    [17-10-04 09:20:53:382 MDT] After: 
    {"FONT_SIZE":18,"ITALIC":false,"HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT":{},"INDENT_END":0,"INDENT_START":0,"LINE_SPACING":1,"UNDERLINE":true,"BACKGROUND_COLOR":"#ffff00","INDENT_FIRST_LINE":0,"SPACING_BEFORE":12,"SPACING_AFTER":0,"STRIKETHROUGH":false,"FOREGROUND_COLOR":"#000000","BOLD":true,"FONT_FAMILY":"Arial","VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT":{}}

UNDERLINE changed from false to true

BACKGROUND_COLOR changed from null to #ffff00
```

But in my document to which this script is bound, the styling of Heading 1 has not changed for existing paragraphs with that Heading.  Nor are new paragraphs marked Heading 1 styled with the changes I've tried to make.

Incidentally, when I run that same function on NORMAL instead of HEADING1, the changes are instantly visible: Every Heading (Normal, Title, Subtitle, Heading 1, etc...) has the underline and background color applied.

I feel like I've fundamentally misunderstood the purpose of these methods (getHeadingAttributes, setHeadingAttributes).  If not these methods, I'd like to find the correct way to re-define Heading stylings for a document.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played around much of this yet, but check the [Enum ParagraphHeading](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading) as it seems close to what you're getting at.

Use the `ParagraphHeading` enumeration to configure the heading style for `ParagraphElement`.

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Append a paragraph, with heading 1.
 var par1 = body.appendParagraph("Title");
 par1.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

 // Append a paragraph, with heading 2.
 var par2 = body.appendParagraph("SubTitle");
 par2.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

 // Append a paragraph, with normal heading.
 var par3 = body.appendParagraph("Text");
 par3.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);
```

Comment: The setHeading method styles a paragraph with whatever the current definition of ParagraphHeading.NORMAL is (or HEADING1, or whatever).  That's not what I'm asking how to do.  I want to change the definition of what NORMAL (or HEADING1 or whatever) is.  This functionality is captured in the standard UI with  the menu choices Format / Paragraph Styles / Normal / Update Normal Text to match...